# How to spawn a new application from Gnome/GTK to a CLI application and read its output back into Gnome/GTK application?

Tags: c, gtk, gnome-terminal

I am trying to spawn a new application from Gnome/GTK to a CLI application and read its output back into my Gnome/GTK application.

The code works as expected for most shell commands but with **tail -f /var/log/messages** and **top** it does not. Is there any way to parse the output from these two commands ?

Am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and libgtk2.0.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *window;          // pointer to window  
static GtkWidget *view;            // pointer to textview
static GtkTextBuffer *buffer;      // pointer to buffer
static GtkTextIter   iter;         // gtktextview iterator 
static GtkWidget *scrolled_window; // pointer to scrolled window

FILE *fp;                          // pointer to stdin/out file pipe
char line[256];                    // line read buffer size

static gboolean on_delete_event (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data){
  gtk_main_quit();  
  return FALSE;
}

void create_gui(){
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "delete_event",
    G_CALLBACK(on_delete_event), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "GUI Front-End for CLI");

    GtkWidget *box = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 10);                // Create a box and 
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);          // set it as window's main child.

    scrolled_window=gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);     // Now create scrolled window...  
    gtk_widget_set_usize(scrolled_window, 650, 450);         // Set scrolled window size..

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), scrolled_window);  // Add scrolled window to vbox.. 
    view = gtk_text_view_new();                              // Create textview..
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), view); // Add textview to scrolled window..
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));  // Assign textview buffer 
    }

void populate(){

 fp = popen("cat /var/log/messages", "r");                   // run shell command using pipe

 while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fp)){                     //
   gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (buffer, &iter);             
   gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &iter, line, -1);
 }  
   pclose(fp);                                               // CLOSE Pipe 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  create_gui();
  populate(); 
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}

// TODO
// fp = popen("ls -al", "r");        
// fp = popen("cat /proc/cpuinfo", "r");        
// fp = popen("cat /var/log/messages", "r");        
// fp = popen("lspci -v", "r");        
// fp = popen("w", "r");        
// fp = popen("last", "r");        
// fp = popen("pstree", "r");         

// fp = popen("tail -f /var/log/messages &", "r");  THIS DOES NOT WORK !      
// fp = popen("top", "r");                          NEITHER DOES THIS..
enter code here
```

Comment: Test `wget` and `git clone` commands. Mostly these two commands will print texts into shell terminal (Running your gtk app from gnome-terminal, and you'll see command output), instead of into GtkTextView. I've tried pipe before, but, yes, only a part command tools works well.

Comment: Hi Liu thank you for trying to help. Let me clarify what I want to do.

For Example:
GTK application calls "ls -a" and then the output of ls is shown in a GTK_TEXTVIEW widget.

This I am able to do but not for TOP or TAIL commands and this is where I require guidance and help.

Thank you very much for your suggestions I will research them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` and `tail -f` are long-running programs (in fact, they never exit), so your strategy of reading the whole output and populating the the textbuffer with it obviously won't work.

Instead, you need to create an *IO channel* that watches what's going on with the pipe, hook the channel into the event loop, and append it to the text buffer as new output arrives. The minimalistic change to your program would be to rewrite the `prepare` function like this:

```
static gboolean data_ready(GIOChannel *channel, GIOCondition cond, gpointer data)
{
  FILE *fp = data;
  char line[256];

  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
      gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter (buffer, &iter);             
      gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &iter, line, -1);
      return TRUE;
  }
  else {
      fclose(fp);
      return FALSE;
  }
}

void populate(){
  FILE *fp = popen("top -b", "r");
  GIOChannel *channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(fileno(fp));
  g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN, data_ready, fp);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did eventually figure out both top and tail -f never exit. For top I figured a workaround of sorts top -n1 -b but that is a one shot thing not what I want to display real time continuous live data. 
Thank you so much for the code sample I am very new to GIOChannel so need to read and educate myself and test-test and test but am sure your code will do what I want to so will mark as correct once I test and verify. Once again very much appreciate your taking the time and your guidance, Thank you.

Comment: @ArunaHewapathirane Note that the code is designed to be dropped into your program without any further modifications. In fact, that is exactly how I tested it.