# is it possible run an app inside another app in GTK?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

My question was about weather it would be possible to embed the contents of a window (such as a terminal emulator, browser, game, or any other X org app) inside of a GTK3 application. This means that the user can still interact with the app and see contents of it. I am running Debian 11 64-bit and I want to make the app using C.

Comment: Do things like the `system()`, or `popen()` commands do what you are thinking?   How about a session that is started up from a call to an exported function within shared library?.  [More ideas here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883462/linux-createprocess)

Comment: @ryyker That would work for terminal applications, but my goal was embedding graphical applications inside other graphical applications.

Comment: [popen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)  is not limited to terminal applications.  It is a library function that can be called from within a program whether its a terminal app, or one with windows/forms/panels.   When called, it opens a pipe to the calling program, then creates a sub-process in which the string command argument is launched.  The string command can be the path-name of any executable, whether it is native to the OS, or one that you have written, eg. `"./my_program.exe"`.  Calls to `popen()` can also be made in such a way as to suppress console popups.

Comment: @ryyker I know, but popen() will open another window. what I want to do is render the contents of a window inside a gtk widget. For example, the same way the ubuntu installer shows a small terminal while installing rather than a terminal popup.

Comment: There are ways to suppress the console from popping up.  Nevertheless, take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248842/how-to-spawn-a-new-application-from-gnome-gtk-to-a-cli-application-and-read-its).

Comment: @ryyker still not what I'm trying to do. I mean almost a virtual machine where the window is running inside of an element in another window. It moves with that window, and closes with that window as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I have seen is using a [`GtkPlug` and a `GtkSocket`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Plug.html):

> Together with GtkSocket, GtkPlug provides the ability to embed widgets
> from one process into another process in a fashion that is transparent
> to the user. One process creates a GtkSocket widget and passes the ID
> of that widget’s window to the other process, which then creates a
> GtkPlug with that window ID. Any widgets contained in the GtkPlug then
> will appear inside the first application’s window.
>
> The communication between a GtkSocket and a GtkPlug follows the [XEmbed
> Protocol](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/xembed-spec/). This protocol has also been implemented in other toolkits,
> e.g. Qt, allowing the same level of integration when embedding a Qt
> widget in GTK+ or vice versa.

An example of this is the [`xfce-settings-manager`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/start), which you can study [here](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings) (search for "socket-id" in the repo).

Notes:

1. `GtkPlug`s and `GtkSocket`s are X11 specific. If you are looking for something cross platform, this might not be it.
2. It seems both of these [no longer exist in Gtk4](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/replacement-for-gtksocket/6268).

Comment: Do you know what happened to the GtkPlug and the GtkSocket in GTK4? I can't find them.

Comment: It seems [they are gone](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/replacement-for-gtksocket/6268)...

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at the [GdkX11](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4-x11/class.X11Screen.html). Not sure what to make of it.